# How to send daily infra usage report to slack using grafana?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I have setup eks cluster with grafana and prometheus for infra monitoring and alerting. I want to send daily infra usage report. This report can include cluster level metrics like maximum node count,pod count etc.

Comment: While I'm not sure how to do this from Grafana, there's probably a way to do something like this with a CronJob, curl+jq, query Prometheus for the metrics you want to post, format your message then post to slack - which could ultimately include links to relevant Grafana dashboards. While from Grafana point of view, there's this: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/reporting/ , generating PDFs, probably not ideal in your case

Comment: Use paid Grafana - reporting is there for this use case https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/enterprise/reporting/